# How to make emphasized zone in the element to be transparent in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, styled-components

I have a slider that is built using `<input type="range">`. And I want to make an emphasized zone background content to be seen clear. [image: Problem image].

I want to get something like that ( I mean when my thumb is over some part of track, then background in this part of track becomes trasparent and content is clearly seen) [image: Expected result]

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slider-parent input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.slider-parent input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #a6a6a6;
  background-color: rgba(237, 231, 225, 0.75);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #f27b7f;
}

.slider-parent input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #a6a6a6;
  border: 2px solid #f27b7f;
  height: 300px;
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(237, 231, 225, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div className="wrapper">
  <Bar>...</Bar>

  <div className="slider-parent">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="600" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to find solution. But found only a few solutions with **background-image** and  **background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(...)** that isn't a match for this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "*I want to get something like...*" - can you clarify exactly what you're showing in that image that you wish to reproduce/implement? The two yellow bars? The transparent overlay? Can you add enough code to your question (please, edit the snippet I created from your posted code, to add the HTML generated by the framework) that we can reproduce a specific (simple) chart?

Comment: To have a background transparent use '`opacity`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest you can do requires some JS, but seems fairly straightforward to implement:

- Put your range graphics in a separate `position: relative` parent container `range-container`.
- Place an empty overlay element `.overlay-element { position: absolute; inset: 0 }` as last element in that parent container. This element will be used to obfuscate the underlying elements (any way you want).
- Modify the `background-image` of that overlay element to your needs.
- Use Javascript to calculate and store the current slider value as a percentage in *custom property* `--toPercent` for use in e.g. a `linear-gradient`.

Tip: overlaying a child element with a semi-transparent parent background color appears the same as making a child element partly transparent.

**pseudo code**

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="main-range-wrapper">
   <input type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="setCurrentRangeValues(this);">

   <div class="range-container">
      <div class="your-graphics">..</div>
      <div class="overlay-element"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
/* CSS */
.main-range-wrapper { --toPercent: 0 }

.range-container    { position: relative; background-color: hsl(0,0%,93.3%) }

.overlay-element {
    position: absolute; inset: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
                          to right,
                          hsl(0,0%,93.3%,0.7) 0%,               /* from */
                          hsl(0,0%,93.3%,0.7) var(--toPercent), /* to   */
                          transparent  var(--toPercent)
                       );
}
```

```js
// Javascript
function setCurrentRangeValues(element) {
    var toPercent = element.value / (element.max / 100);
    var wrapper   = document.querySelector('.main-range-wrapper');

    wrapper.style.setProperty("--toPercent" , toPercent + '%' );
};
```

I had already created a responsive [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/Expxwwo) *custom range slider* some time ago. Inserting the fucntionality you need took mere minutes.

**Running snippet below** uses the forementioned Codepen with most of the code intact so you have something to toy with. Scan the code for 'SO76399916' to see relevant code.

```js
// Assign event listener
window.onload = window.onchange = window.onresize = function () {
    setScaleSizeVars();
};

/* container element involved */
const scale = document.getElementById("scale");

function setScaleSizeVars() {
    // Modify CSS custom variable to hold current element width/height
    scale.style.setProperty("--clientWidth" , scale.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    scale.style.setProperty("--clientHeight", scale.getBoundingClientRect().height); // not used
};

function setInfoValues(element) {
    // Store current slider value in a custom property
    scale.style.setProperty('--scale-value', element.value); 

    // For SO76399916
    // linear-gradient percentage from range slider current value
    var toPercent = element.value / (element.max / 100);
    scale.style.setProperty("--toPercent" , toPercent + '%' );

    document.getElementById('infoN').innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById('infoR').innerHTML = ' > ' + element.value;

    document.getElementById('range').value  =
    document.getElementById('number').value = element.value;
};
```

```css
/*************************/
/* Slider specific rules */
/*************************/
 .scale {
    --scale-value: 0;  /* current value, mod by inline JS */

     /* SO76399916 */
    --toPercent  : 0%; /* obfuscator linear gradient percentage */

     /*
        Define variables used by .scale and descendants
     */
     --max-range : 250;   /* set equal to range slider 'max' */
     --arrow-size: 1.5em; /* actually its font size */

     /* define custom gradient(s) */
     --gradient1: linear-gradient(
                    90deg, 
                    aqua   , #00bcff, #007aff,
                    #0037ff, #0b00ff, #4e00ff,
                    #9000ff, #d300ff, #ff00e9,
                    #ff00a6, #ff0064, #ff0021,
                    #ff2100, #ff6400, #ffa600,
                    #ffe900, #d3ff00, #90ff00,
                    #4eff00, #0bff00, #00ff37,
                    #00ff7a, #00ffbc, aqua
                );
}

.scale-container {
    display: flex; width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 2.5rem 1rem 1rem;

    font-size: calc(1.25vmin + 0.25rem); /* (320,8)(1280,20) */
}

.scale {
    position: relative;
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; width: 100%;

   /* Using a custom var to enable easy change of the gradient */
    --gradient: var(--gradient1);
}

.scale :is(.headers,.values) { display: flex; width: 100% }

/* For variable horizontal distribution */
[col="1"] { flex: 1 } /* Flexbox will try to assign     */
[col="2"] { flex: 2 } /* space to an element based      */
[col="3"] { flex: 3 } /* on the 'flex-grow' values.     */
[col="4"] { flex: 4 } /* The result is a container with */
[col="5"] { flex: 5 } /* uneven sized child elements.   */
[col="6"] { flex: 6 } /* A hidden pearl of 'flex-grow'. */

.scale .headers {
    background-image     : var(--gradient, none); /* with fallback */
    background-size      : cover;
    background-position  : center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat    : no-repeat;
}

.scale .values > * { flex: 1 } /* even distribution */

.scale-container .legend {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
}

/***************************************/
/* Obfuscation filter (for SO76399916) */
/***************************************/
.range-container {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-element {
    position: absolute; inset: 0;

    background-image: linear-gradient(
                          to right,
                          hsl(0,0%,93.3%,0.7) 0%,               /* from */
                          hsl(0,0%,93.3%,0.7) var(--toPercent), /* to   */
                          transparent  var(--toPercent)
                       );
}

/*****************************/
/* Arrow layout and movement */
/*****************************/
.scale .arrow {
    position: absolute; z-index: 1;

    font-size: var(--arrow-size);

    /* negative font-size * arrow size */
    top: calc(-0.8 * var(--arrow-size));

    /* Arrow offset */
    --offset: calc(var(--arrow-size) / 4 + 2px);

    /* Movement along horizontal scale, clientWidth determined in JS */
    left: min( var(--clientWidth) * 1px - var(--offset),
              (var(--clientWidth) * var(--scale-value) / var(--max-range)) * 1px - var(--offset) );
    /*
       - Set the arrow left margin relative to the JS parent width using the current slider value
         minus the arrow offset to get passed left/right parent width.
       - Use min(..) to make sure it halts at the end.
    */
}

/***********/
/* Globals */
/***********/

 *    { box-sizing: border-box }          /* define box-model */

:root { font-size: 1rem }                 /* get browser default font size */

body {
    margin: unset;                        /* remove default spacing */
    padding: 1rem 2rem;                   /* define new spacing */

    font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem); /* (320,14)(1280,20) */
    line-height: 1.5;
}

label, input         { display: block; font-size: 1em }
input[type="range"]  { width: 100% }
input[type="number"] { width: 4em }


/*************/
/* eye-candy */
/*************/
.scale-container                 { font-size: calc(1.25vmin + 0.25rem); /* (320,8)(1280,20) */ }
.scale .arrow                    { vertical-align: text-bottom; /**/line-height: 1; color: DimGray }

.scale :is(.headers,.values) > * { text-align: center }
.scale .headers > *              { border-left: 1px solid white }
.scale .headers>:first-child     { border-left: none }

.scale .values > :first-child    { text-align: start  }
.scale .values > :last-child     { text-align: end    }

.scale .values > *               { background-color: Silver; color: DimGray }
```

```html
<label>value [0 - 250]<span id="infoR"></span>
    <input type="range" id="range"
           min="0" max="250" step="1" value="0"
           oninput="setInfoValues(this);">
</label>

<label>number value<span id="infoN"></span>
    <input type="number" id="number"
           min="0" max="250" step="1" value="0"
           oninput="setInfoValues(this);">
</label>

<br><br>
<div class="scale-container">
    <div id="scale" class="scale">
        <div class="arrow">&#129139;</div>

        <div class="range-container">
            <div class="headers">
                <div col="4">A+</div>
                <div col="2">A</div>
                <div col="4">B</div>
                <div col="4">C</div>
                <div col="5">D</div>
                <div col="3">E</div>
                <div col="5">F</div>
                <div col="5">G</div>
                <div col="1">H</div>
            </div>
            <div class="values">
                <div>  0</div>
                <div> 25</div>
                <div> 50</div>
                <div> 75</div>
                <div>100</div>
                <div>125</div>
                <div>150</div>
                <div>175</div>
                <div>200</div>
                <div>225</div>
                <div>&gt;250</div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay-element"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="legend">
        <div>headers</div>
        <div>values </div>
    </div>
</div>
```